# wp_mail() in a loop, only sending to last address

Tags: php, wordpress, email, loops

I'm using a plugin that allows you to send an e-mail to `x` amount of people. All you have to do is enter their "name" and "e-mail address". These entries are named `friend_name[0]` & `friend_email[0]` respectively. There are `+` & `-` buttons for adding and removing entry fields. The number in the `$key` goes up and down relative to the number of fields. I have confirmed all the `$keys` change on the entry form.

When the form is submitted and is processed through the loop, the e-mails all send, but only to the last e-mail entered. So if I enter 5 names and 5 e-mails, they send with this data:

**Name:** John Doe 1
**E-Mail:** JohnDoe5@gmail.com

**Name:** John Doe 2
**E-Mail:** JohnDoe5@gmail.com

**Name:** John Doe 3
**E-Mail:** JohnDoe5@gmail.com

**Name:** John Doe 4
**E-Mail:** JohnDoe5@gmail.com

**Name:** John Doe 5
**E-Mail:** JohnDoe5@gmail.com

Here's the loop:

```
function invfr_sendmail() {
$post = ( !empty( $_POST ) ) ? true : false;

if( $post ) {
    $subject = invfr_get_settings( 'subject' );
    $message = invfr_get_settings( 'message' );
    $friends = $_POST['friend_email'];
    $headers = "From:" . $_POST['user_name'] . " <" . $_POST['user_email']. ">" . "\r\n";
    $errors = array();
    foreach ( $friends as $key => $friend ) {
        $name = stripslashes( $_POST['friend_name'][$key] );
        $email = trim( $_POST['friend_email'][$key] );

        // Check name
        if( !$name )
            $errors[] = '#friend_name-' . $key;

        if( !$email )
            $errors[] = '#friend_email-' . $key;

        if( $email && !is_email( $email ) )
            $errors[] = '#friend_email-' . $key;
    }

    // send email 
    if( !$errors ) {
        foreach ( $friends as $key => $friend )
            $mail = wp_mail( $email, invfr_tokens_replacement( $subject, $_POST, $key ), invfr_tokens_replacement( $message, $_POST, $key ), invfr_tokens_replacement( $headers, $_POST, $key ) );
        if( $mail )
            echo 'sent';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach ( $friends as $key => $friend )` loop is rewriting the `$name` and `$email` variables every time, so at the end they'll just have the last value. You should store this data in an array after your error checks:

```
    // Check name and email 
    $data_missing = false;
    if( ! $name ) {
        $errors[] = '#friend_name-' . $key;
        $data_missing = true;
    } 
    if ( ! $email || ! is_email( $email) ) {
        $errors[] = '#friend_email-' . $key;
        $data_missing = true;
    } 
    if ( ! $data_missing ) {
        $email_data[] = array( 'name' => $name, 'email' => $email );
    }
```

Then, loop through this array in your send mail part:

```
if ( ! empty( $email_data) ) {
    foreach( $email_data as $data ) {
        $name = $data['name'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $mail = wp_mail( .... )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I will try this, and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing with the code you gave me:

http://pastebin.com/g5pWQBz2

Getting some kind of error, but it's not any type thats getting logged. I think I have a section in the wrong bracket.

Comment: Looks ok, hope it works for you. If so, please click on `accept answer`. Afterwards, you can think about what you want to do with those errors and if you want to give some feedback about the sent mails. Happy coding!

Comment: In my adding of your code, I wrongfully removed the $email and $name variables. This is working now! Except I think I have to add back the bit about `if( $mail ) echo 'sent';` so it stops spinning and whatnot.

THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: Hey! I ran into a small problem. Everything works in the background, except the success message. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19817876/2076384

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot simply `echo` messages from a plugin function. Where would you expect the message to show? If your function is called, for example, at the WP `init` hook, there isn't even a page rendered yet. For the admin side there are the admin notices, but for front end you have to add some hook of your own and call it in your theme. There's a little more on the subject [in this question (read the comments as well!)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75035/is-there-anything-like-admin-notices-for-front-end)

Comment: For some reason it's working now. Your PHP worked fantastic, but wasn't triggering the jQuery. I spent a while messing with it before setting it back to just the PHP you gave me... and it worked. I don't know why, but I won't question it. I'll be sacrificing a lamb on this date every year in sacrifice to whatever minor deity is making it work. THANK YOU AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: I wrote an aswer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822819/php-mail-function-not-notifying-jquery-of-success-failure/19829361#19829361) showing how to send replies via AJAX.