# WordPress: wp_mail function only works once in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a cron with a function to delete old events (based on a custom field).
The function works find and deletes all events which lie in the past.
So far so good...

Now I want to send an email to the author of the event, that the event has been deleted. I'm doing this with an extra `wp_mail` function inside a foreach.

The problem now is, that only the last of the old events gets deleted. Maybe this has somesthing to do with the variables for the mail (`$post`, `$author`, ...) inside the foreach?

I read something about that issue here but I don't understand it: [wp_mail() in a loop, only sending to last address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817591/wp-mail-in-a-loop-only-sending-to-last-address)

Here is my code:

```
function get_delete_old_events() {

    $past_query = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));

    // Set our query arguments
    $args = [
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => 'event', // Post type
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
                'key'     => 'gid_22', // Replace this with the event end date meta key.
                'value'   => $past_query,
                'compare' => '<='
            ]
        ]
      ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if we have posts to delete, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // OK, we have posts to delete, lets delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )

        /* start e-mail  */
            $headers[] = 'From: SITENAME <hello@domain.com>';

            $post       = get_post($id);
            $author     = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $subject    = "SUBJECT: ".$post->post_title."";

            $message = "THE MESSAGE BODY";

            wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
        /* end e-mail */

        wp_trash_post( $id );
}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'old_event_delete', 'get_delete_old_events' );


// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_events_delete_event');

function register_daily_events_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'old_event_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'old_event_delete' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems like it must work properly. Can you share that code which was working well before editing the mail function?

Comment: The code which was working fine is the same code as in my question. except the code between the commented section "start e-mail"  and "end e-mail"

Comment: maybe you need to use reset data function let me share the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
function get_delete_old_events() {
    $past_query = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => array( 'event' ), //post type
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',//fetch all posts,
        'meta_query'     =>array(
                                    'relation'  => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                            'key' => 'gid_22',
                                            'value' =>  $past_query,
                                            'compare'   => '<='
                                          )
                                  )
        );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            // do something
            $headers[] = 'From: SITENAME <hello@domain.com>';

            $postid     = get_the_ID();
            $post       = get_post($postid);
            $author     = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $subject    = "SUBJECT: ".get_the_title()."";

            $message = "THE MESSAGE BODY";

            wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
            wp_trash_post( $id );
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
        return false;

    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: sorry now please check i wrap the variable as a string previously. $past_query i wrap it as a string

Comment: Thanks.. Good day

Answer (score 1):

`wp_mail` function returns bool (See [Wordpress Documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)). So, it exits the function as it returns the value in it's first iteration.

Just add a variable before the wp_mail

```
 $is_sent = wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

It should work then.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working yet. Maybe we need to store the other variables  too?

Comment: Well, may be. Please check the WP documentation. If they return something and it is not handled by some variable, then you may need to.